# What's the connection between "Recently modified in Quick Launch" and the "SharePoint Server Publishing"-Feature?

Tags: 2010, feature, publishing

First I had a plain Team Site without the Feauture "SharePoint Server Publishing" activated. I created several Site Pages, all rendered automatically without the annoying "Recently Modified".

When I activated the "SharePoint Server Publishing"-Feature all my pages now show the "Recently Modified" in the Quicklaunch. Even after Deactivating the feature, the damage is done.

What is the connection between those two things, so I can cut it off?

**EDIT:** 
Unfortunately neither do I have control over the site collection nor do I have access to the filesystem. The question is: How do I get back to the state of "not having 'Recently Modified' in my Quicklaunch" by default, (without making changes to the site collection, the filesystem or the masterpage and without Visual Studio)?

Answer (score 1):

Find  "wkpstd.aspx" file in 14\template open that up and find the "SharePoint:RecentChangesMenu" server control and then simply add visible=”false” save changes to file and refresh your page and it will work as it worked for me once.

I think your confuse by what this feature does so I would recommend you read this [Blog](http://sharepointchick.com/archive/2011/06/23/sharepoint-publishing-features-functionality.aspx)

**EDIT**

Sorry but I don't think you can do it

> without making changes to the site collection, the filesystem or the
>   masterpage and without Visual Studio

Comment: Unfortunately I can't access or manipulate the fs. The blog post is interesting, though I didn't find any hint which aspect triggers the "Recently Modified" thing.

Comment: upload a new master page if your current one isn't customized :) since you can activate features I guess you can upload master pages as well ;)

Comment: that's the first thing which came to my mind as well ;) but editing the masterpage is prohibited, too.

Comment: lol is it customized or default sharepoint master page?

Comment: it is customized

Answer (score 0):

I hope this explains it for you in detail, it shows you how to hide/disable without effecting other features :)

http://johndandison.com/blog/post/2010/01/25/Removing-the-e28098Recently-Modifiede28099-from-the-Quick-Launch-e28093-SharePoint-2010.aspx

**EDIT**

> Go to  "Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\14\Template\DocumentTemplates" .
>
> Open "wkpstd.aspx" file.  Search for tag
>   "SharePoint:RecentChangesMenu".  Add visible="false"  at the end of
>   this tag.  Save this file & refresh SharePoint site .

http://sharepointgauravgoyal.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/hide-recently-modified-items.html

appart from changing the above or masterpage or css then off the top of my head you would probable need to create a feature that would be farm scoped or web scoped that does the above for you :)

hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I knew the css snippet to get rid of it from single sites via a form-webpart or the masterpage. Unfortunately it doesn't solve the issue, as nobody wants to modify each website because editing the masterpage in my case is no option.

Comment: iv ammended my question for you :)

Comment: it's a shame I can't access the fs here... I didn't use development tools to get into this problem, just the feature - so now I am looking for a way out of this on the same path ;)